# Validating looped checkboxes using

Tags: php, html, mysqli

How do I Validate checkboxes. One or more of them must be checked before the user can proceed to the next page using JavaScript and with a form like this?

```
        echo "<form method="POST" action="confirm.php">";
          $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT data
                                                FROM details;");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)){            
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            echo "<h5><input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='".$row['data']."'>Apple";
        }

    }
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: You get reputation points for accepting an answer

Comment: I'm actually very new to this community and I didn't know there's such thing. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate them for what? You could do something like:

```
$("form").on("click", "input[type=submit]", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // check your inputs here .. if everything is good then do whatever
}
```